# How to assign a compact manifold with boundary to every manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I vaguely believe that given a manifold without boundary $M$, it "naturally" corresponds to a compact manifold with boundary $\tilde{M}$. For instance, the cylinder corresponds to the closed cylinder, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ corresponds to the closed disc $D^2$. However, I cannot make this point clear. I once thought that if $M$ can be embedded in an Euclidean space, then its closure can be defined as $\tilde{M}$. But this definition is not intrinsic and has some problems because $\mathbb{R}^2$ may be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $S^2\backslash \{pt\}$, whose closure is $S^2$ instead of $D^2$. Then how to make my idea clear?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would read this question as "Is there a natural/functorial way to embed a manifold without boundary canonically into a compact manifold with boundary".

Comment: You could enforce the condition that the natural  "bounded closure" you are looking for does not contain any new points except boundary points. Then the sphere would not qualify, since it adds a non-boundary point.

Comment: One way to interpret this is as asking whether a manifold with boundary can be (naturally) embedded as the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. Naturality questions aside, this is not always possible (e.g. it forces f.g. homology).

Comment: @Thorgott 's interpretation to my question is wonderful, but are there any specific  manifolds that do not satisfy this statement? I also want to know under what conditions (such as $M$ is differential manifold or something else) does the statement hold? Any further explanation or links related to this topic are helpful.

Comment: Yes, the interior of a compact manifold with boundary has finitely generated homology in all degrees, but not all manifolds without boundary do, for example a surface of infinite genus does not. Beyond that, there are much subtler end-theoretic obstructions. In dimensions $>5$, these conditions have been fully worked out by Siebenmann in his thesis, but I can't help with that more than give the reference ([here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/tom-readings/Siebenmann%20thesis.pdf)).